# How to pass json data to aws lambda through API Gateway?

Tags: flutter, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to send the JSON to AWS lambda to trigger lambda handler. I am using Flutter web for this project and my API end point is as below. Below is my code to hit AWS lambda endpoint.

```
  Future<String> getResponse(jsonData) async {
    var response =
        await http.post(Uri.parse("https://7jua06h1r4.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/stage1/calc"), headers: header, body: jsonData);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Success");
    } else {
      print("Error");
    }
  }
```

When I try to hit and get response using postman, everything works fine and i get 200 status with response as well. But when i test it using my browser, it display the body is empty. Can you help me out please? How can i pass JSON data through API Gateway to lambda?

```
{"statusCode": 200, "body": {}}
```

When i try using Postman, it works as expected. you can see in the image below:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tczfw.png

My Lambda function:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event['body'])
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': event['body']
    }
```

Here, i am not able to get the body i.e. JSON Data from my app.

Comment: Can you try printing jsonData before you do the request ?

Comment: Yes, Before calling the getResponse method, I can get JSON output in my console.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your code need to replace it:

```
print(event['body'])
```

by

```
print(event.body.body)
```

Event is not the call body, body is inside of that object and you have an attribute called **body**.

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested. The following error occured.                         ` {"errorMessage": "'dict' object has no attribute 'body'", "errorType": "AttributeError", "stackTrace": [["/var/task/lambda_function.py", 19, "generateCV", "data = event.body.body"]]} `

Comment: ¿Could you send me the code? I don't see any dict Object.
¿Could you print EVENT?

Answer (score 0):

When you tested it using your browser, did you pass body to the url? Assuming that you just typed your url

> https://7jua06h1r4.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/stage1/calc

into the browser, you would have gotten an empty body in response, which is the correct behaviour.

Comment: Actually, as you can see in postman image.. actually, that was the error i am trying to solve. I don't understand how can i send json data in the lambda. although you can see that in the function, i have passed the data. But i think, AWS API gateway is not taking the data thus, the lambda shows empty body.

Comment: in api gateway you can choose to do an lambda proxy integration by pointing the lambda function you have choosen to the api gateway. By doing this, api gateway will pass the event object it obtained to the lambda. this video may help: https://youtu.be/uFsaiEhr1zs?t=409

Comment: I have watched that video, I wanted to send an entire json at once. But in the video i have to give fields manually. And also,when I use Lambda Proxy, it throws CORS error.

Comment: if the postman is working, it means that lambda is already connected to api gateway. If you have doubt on whether lambda is connected to api gateway, try to make your lambda function to     
`return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'test': 'yes',
        'body': event['body']
    }`
and run postman again, you should see api gateway return with 'test' field now

Comment: As you can see on the lambda code, I have a return status and body. When i make pass data from my browser, I get return 200 status, however, the body field return empty value. So, i guess the json data is not reaching to the lambda. The POST request from flutter is also there. Can you have a look into that please. Thank You :)